# Extract useful data from twitter search api using Node.js

Tags: node.js, twitter

I need to get information like created_at, retweet_count from twitter search api,
here is my code to search from twitter

```
app.get('/tweets', function (req, res) {
    client.get('search/tweets', params, function (err, data, response) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(data)
            //var lines = data.split(" ")
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log(data[i].created_at)
                console.log(data[i].id)
                console.log(data[i].text)
                console.log(data[i].user)
                console.log(data[i].retweet_count)
            }
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
})
```

This is working fine and i am getting this in my console

```
 { statuses:
   [ { created_at: 'Sat Sep 16 06:24:04 +0000 2017',
       id: 908939524637470700,
       id_str: '908939524637470720',
       text: 'Re: Which market holds more coins? Japan or Korean. #Bitcoin_Discussion #bitcoin #blockchain',
       truncated: false,
       entities: [Object],
       metadata: [Object],
       source: '<a href="https://dlvrit.com/" rel="nofollow">dlvr.it</a>',
       in_reply_to_status_id: null,
       in_reply_to_status_id_str: null,
       in_reply_to_user_id: null,
       in_reply_to_user_id_str: null,
       in_reply_to_screen_name: null,
       user: [Object],
       geo: null,
       coordinates: null,
       place: null,
       contributors: null,
       is_quote_status: false,
       retweet_count: 0,
       favorite_count: 0,
       favorited: false,
       retweeted: false,
       possibly_sensitive: false,
       lang: 'en' }, .... so on
```

I need to extract created_at, id, retweet_count from this data, can anyone help me here ...

Comment: I see that you've fetched data from twitter. Do you need help in reading the response?

Comment: As per api response `data` is an object, `data.statuses` is an array. So iterate through `data.statuses` in your for loop instead of `data`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by Prakash, you simply need to iterate over `data.statuses`:

```
var aStatusList = data.statuses;

for(let aStatus of aStatusList) {
    console.log("Created at    : " + aStatus.created_at);
    console.log("id            : " + aStatus.id);
    console.log("retweet_count : " + aStatus.retweeted);
}
```